# Check if net share is mapped correctly in cmd file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i'm creating a script .cmd that use this command:

```
net use y: \\serverip\folder  /u:domain\user passwd
```

After this i need to check if the folder is mapped correctly and send an email if don't.
How can i do this? thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
IF EXIST Y:\NUL GOTO USE_MY_NEW_DRIVE_Y
```